# Isomorphism of the etale fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Given a birational proper morphism $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$
of complex algebraic varieties. 
It is always true that $f^* \colon \pi^{et}_1 (X)\rightarrow \pi^{et}_1(Y)$
is an isomorphism?
I think that this follows from (SGA.1 exp X. Corollary 1.4)
But im not totally sure.

Thanks, in advance.